# PHP if/else statement issue

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm having some issues with this statement,

```
<?php 
    $cert_mess = $vehicle['make'];
    if ($vehicle["make"] == "Honda" && $vehicle["Certified"] == "0")  {
        $cert_mess = "DFWCertAutos";
    }
    elseif ($vehicle["make"] == "Cadillac" && $vehicle["Certified"] == "0") {
        $cert_mess = "DFWCertAutos";
    }
    elseif (!in_array($vehicle['make'], array('Cadillac','Honda') )) {
        $cert_mess = "DFWCertAutos";
    }
?>
<div style="font-size:10px; padding:10px; padding-top: 0px;">*This car is <?php 
echo $cert_mess ?> certified.</div>
```

Any suggestions? currently it just displays `$cert_mess` as 'make' and ignores the if / else if statements.

Comment: Probably none of your if statements execute due to bad logic? Have you even tried to debug it?

Comment: What is your input? `var_dump($vehicle)`

Comment: Are you sure `$vehicle['make']` is set in the beginnig?

Comment: Actually I just figured it out - did a var_dump and "certified" was correct not "Certified". Thanks for the help! Any recommendations to make this code a little cleaner/simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler code can be the following:

```
$cert_mess = $vehicle['make'];
if (($vehicle["make"] == "Honda" && $vehicle["Certified"] == "0")
    || ($vehicle["make"] == "Cadillac" && $vehicle["Certified"] == "0")
    || !in_array($vehicle['make'], array('Cadillac','Honda'))
) {
    $cert_mess = "DFWCertAutos";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler still:

```
$cert_mess = $vehicle['make'];
if (!in_array($vehicle['make'], array('Cadillac', 'Honda')) || $vehicle['certified'] == '0')
{
    $cert_mess = 'DFWCertAutos';
}
```